# Eu gostaria de imprimir o seguinte resultado mostrado abaixo do código

Tags: php

Quero usar a função array_map, para adicionar mais valores ao meu array.

Quando a pessoa tiver menos de 18 anos.
adicionar a chave **"entrada"** com o valor **"negado"**
e quando for maior maior ou igual a 18 adicionar **"entrada" => "permitida"**.

resultado que quero

```
["nome" => "Diovane", "Idade" => 22, "Entrada" => "permitida"]
["nome" => "Ana",     "Idade" => 17, "Entrada" => "negada"]
```

```
<?php
$pessoa = array(
    ["Nome" => "Diovane", "Idade" => 22],
    ["Nome" => "Ana", "Idade" => 17],
    ["Nome" => "Dani", "Idade" => 18],
    ["Nome" => "Soraia", "Idade" => 24],
    ["Nome" => "Anny", "Idade" => 3],
    ["Nome" => "Sergio", "Idade" => 17],
    ["Nome" => "Michele", "Idade" => 22]
);

// Array Map
$entradaBuate = array_map(function($pessoa) {

},$pessoa);

print_r($entradaBuate);
```

Comment: Legal o código... Qual é a sua pergunta? Qual é a sua dificuldade? O que é que você está tentando fazer?

Comment: Eu queria imprimir o seguinte resultado mas não estou sabendo: ["Nome" => "Diovane", "Idade" => 17, "Entrada" => "Negada"] caso a idade fosse menor que 18 e ["Nome" => "Diovane", "Idade" => 22, "Entrada" => "permitida"]

Comment: @Diovane mano já resolvi seu problema, mas não consigo postar a resposta, está fechado para respostas.

Comment: @Diovane quando fizer perguntas, precisa ser muito claro com a sua dificuldade e a solução que você precisa mano. porém eu entendi, editei a sua pergunta pra poder postar a resposta.